# Rust lib refer to names in bin crate

Tags: rust

Is it possible to define a lib crate in rust that refers to items defined in a bin crate?  How do you do it?

Suppose that they are in the same package. I have spent a long time searching the documentation but I cannot find it.

Comment: I believe rustc would be fine with this, but cargo does not support it. Just put the shared items in the lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

No crate can depend on a binary crate - dependencies can only be library crates - not even in the same package. So you cannot import items from a binary crate.

If you want to share code between, it must be the other way around.

Comment: Since OP mentions "same package". Then I feel like it should be mentioned, that since a package can produce one-to-many binaries and zero-or-one library. That _technically_ it "is" possible. To the extend that they can both specify the same `mod ...`

Comment: @vallentin Only by using a very lax interpretation of "items defined in a bin crate"... If both define same module, then the library is *not* using anything from the binary, the library has defined its own items.

Comment: To be fair, I do agree with you completely. I was just interpreting the second paragraph of "Suppose that they are in the same package", as OP maybe just phrasing the actual question loosely